# How to change the check/un-check the Checkbox on rowClick in Antd table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, user-experience, antd

While using the AntD table component (https://2x.ant.design/components/table/#), I am facing an issue that onRowclick event I am not able to check the checkbox or radio button placed in that row in order to make the selection.

I tried rowSelection and OnRow fields associated with the table but unable to accomplish the desired behavior.

Can someone please provide some pointers?

Thanks